# Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I print custom socks and have one that says "Do not disturb, Alex's watching the darts", Is this correct as i keep having customers complain it makes no sense,

Answer (score 1):

If Alex is watching a darts match, either in person or on TV (these are very popular in the UK) then the slogan on the socks makes perfect sense. Some might question the use of *Alex's* as a contraction of *Alex is*, considering it unnecessary, but it is neither incorrect nor does it 'make no sense'.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it means "Alex is watching the darts", and as both would sound the same in speech, there is no reason to write it as "Alex's".

Comment: It might look more chatty with an apostrophe-s.

Comment: "and all I could think about is that Alex's going to blow his knee out." US hockey player quoted on ESPN

Comment: Technically it's correct, but I don't think it is common to write "Alex's" instead of "Alex is". The second is clearer, and is just as quick to pronounce. This is different from, for example, "Mark's", as this is one syllable, whereas "Mark is" is two.